# How to pass a selected value from nested object to chip

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object of the following type:

```json
[
  {
    "insInvolvementId": "01",
    "clientId": "AB",
    "client": {
      "firstName": "JAMCN",
      "middleName": null,
      "lastName": "PERGY"
    },
    "involvementRole": [
      {
        "involvementRoleId": "01A",
        "insInvolvedId": "01",
        "involvementRoleDescription": "Driver"
      },
      {
        "involvementRoleId": "01B",
        "insInvolvedId": "01",
        "involvementRoleDescription": "Owner"
      },
      {
        "involvementRoleId": "01C",
        "insInvolvedId": "01",
        "involvementRoleDescription": "Insured"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have the following code snippet to render the object:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CLAIMS from './Participant_data';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({

  typography : {
    fontSize:'3.5 rem',
    fontWeight:'550',
    color:'#0E1941',
    marginBottom:'30px',
  
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      fontSize: '0.5rem',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      fontSize: '1.0rem',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      fontSize: '1.2rem',
    }
  },

  font_class : {
   font: 'normal normal 900 20px/24px Allstate Sans',
  //  letter-spacing: '0px',
   color: '#0E1941',
   opacity: '1',
   fontSize:'1.2rem'
  }
}));


const Checkbox = (props) => {
    // creates all the checkbox based on the list array.
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    const checkbox = props.list.map((m) => (
      //  <span key={m.key}>
      m.involvementRole.map((role) => (
      <div>
      <table>
        <tbody style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          {/* {CLAIMS.map((m) => */}
          
              <tr>
                <td style={{ width: "60px" }}>
                  {" "}
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id = {role.involvementRoleDescription}
                    onClick={() => props.handleCheckboxChange(m)
                    }
                  />
                </td>
                <td style={{ width: "250px" }} value={role.involvementRoleDescription}>
                  {role.involvementRoleDescription}
                </td>
                <td style={{ width: "250px" }}>
                  {m.client.firstName + " " + m.client.lastName}
                </td>
                
              </tr>
            
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    ))
    
    ));
    

  
    return (
      <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
         <div style={{backgroundColor:'#E9E9E9' , width:'100%' , marginTop:'10px' , 
         marginBottom:'10px'}}> <typography variant="body1" className={classes.typography} style= 
         {{marginTop:'10px' , marginBottom:'30px' , font: "normal normal medium 20px/24px Allstate 
         Sans W"}}> {props.title} </typography></div>
        <div className = {classes.font_class}>{checkbox}</div>
       
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Checkbox;
```

on click of the checkbox an array or selected values will be created and the selected values will be passed to the chip

```
 const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([]);

          const handlePerformerDelete = (chipToDelete) => () => {
            setChipData((chips) => chips.filter((chip) => chip.key !== chipToDelete.key));
            console.log(chipData);
          };
        
          const handleCheckboxChange = (insInvolvementId, setParticipants) => {
            setParticipants((currentParticipants) =>
             currentParticipants.includes(insInvolvementId )
               ? currentParticipants.filter((f) => f !== insInvolvementId)
               : [...currentParticipants, insInvolvementId]
           
               
           );    
             };
             console.log(claimParticipants);
            
           const handleSubmit=()=>{
    setChipData(claimParticipants);}
```

The object I have rendered on screen is something like this
[image]

I want the firstname,lastname and role desc to be passes to the chip but I am not able to get the specific role for the checkbox we clicked.

Comment: where is code of checkbox?

Comment: You do not have "a JSON", you have "an object"

Comment: @AshishKamble the method handleCheckboxChange is getting triggered on clicking the checkbox